# Configuración Watchdog (Perrito guardián)

Tags: raspberry-pi

Muy buenas a todos!

Me gustaría saber como puedo configurar el archivo **Watchdog**. Quisiera que este programa comprobara si se está ejecutando por ejemplo un vídeo con el reproductor **VLC**, para ello tengo entendido que debería estar haciendo comprobaciones a cada rato (por ejemplo cada 3 mins) y en el caso de que no se encontrara el **PID** de ese proceso, por algún error interno, etc... que el sistema se reiniciara.

Estoy trabajando en un `Raspberry Pi` 3 con `Debian 9`.
He ejecutado los siguientes comandos en la terminal:

```
- modprobe bcm2708_wdog
- modprobe bcm2835_wdt
- echo "bcm2835_wdt" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
- chkconfig watchdog on
- nano /etc/watchdog.conf
```

Me quedé ahí. Si alguien tiene alguna idea o algún consejo, me serviría de gran ayuda.

Un saludo.
David.

Comment: por que la etiqueta de PHP?

Comment: Quise poner "watchdog", "Raspberry", "Problemas", pero no me dejaba publicarlo. Espero que lo entienda, señor.

Answer (score -1):

En ese caso puedes hacer uso de crontab
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Por un lado puedes crear un script sencillo que vea si algo se esta ejecutando un determinado programa con el comando preg
https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep

Ej.

```
preg vlc
```

Devuelve el numero de proceso vlc.
Si no existe, puedes volver a ejecutarlo.